# Java StringBuilder how to not print "to" at the end

Tags: java, loops, concatenation, stringbuilder

My stringbuilder travelROute is printing "Destination1 to Destination2 to Destination 3 to", how can I avoid getting "to" at the end of the string?

```
ArrayList<String> itinerary = new ArrayList<String>();
Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
String userChoice;
String upperCase;

while (true) {
    System.out.print("Destination: ");
    userChoice = kb.next();
    upperCase = userChoice.toUpperCase();
    if (upperCase.equals("DONE")) {
        break;
    } else
        itinerary.add(userChoice);

}

StringBuilder travelRoute = new StringBuilder();
for (int count = 0; count < itinerary.size(); count++) {
    String upperCaseDestination = itinerary.get(count).toUpperCase();
    travelRoute.append(upperCaseDestination + " to");
}

System.out.println(travelRoute);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using [`StringJoiner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html) available since Java 8.

```
StringJoiner travelRoute = new StringJoiner(" to ");
for (int count = 0; count < itinerary.size(); count++) {
    String upperCaseDestination = itinerary.get(count).toUpperCase();
    travelRoute.add(upperCaseDestination);
}
```

You can also improve readability of your code by using [enhanced for loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html)

```
StringJoiner travelRoute = new StringJoiner(" to ");
for (String data : itinerary) {
    travelRoute.add(data.toUpperCase());
}
```

or streams

```
String route = itinerary.stream()
        .map(s -> s.toUpperCase())
        .collect(Collectors.joining(" to "));

System.out.println(route);
```

Answer (score 3):

Two ways to solve this common problem:

1. Add `"to"` in *front* of terms, *except* the first
2. Add it after every term, then clean up after the loop

Code for 1:

```
StringBuilder travelRoute = new StringBuilder(); 
for(int count = 0; count < itinerary.size() ; count++) {
    if (count > 0) {
        travelRoute.append(" to "); 
    }
    String upperCaseDestination = itinerary.get(count).toUpperCase();
    travelRoute.append(upperCaseDestination); 
}
```

Code for 2:

```
// after loop
travelRoute.setLength(travelRoute.length() - 3);
```

Personally, I prefer option 1.

Answer (score 2):

The most elegant solution is to use an appender.

```
StringBuilder travelRoute = new StringBuilder();
String appender = "";
for (int count = 0; count < itinerary.size(); count++) {
    String upperCaseDestination = itinerary.get(count).toUpperCase();
    travelRoute.append(appender).append(upperCaseDestination);
    appender = " to ";
}
```

It makes the solution easy to read in the future, should you need to come back and modify your code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the modified code portion. if-else condition inside for-loop is cpu consuming so this way is the best one I think

```
 StringBuilder travelRoute = new StringBuilder(); 
        for(int count = 0; count < itinerary.size()-1 ; count++)
        {
            String upperCaseDestination = itinerary.get(count).toUpperCase();
            travelRoute.append(upperCaseDestination + " to"); 
        }
         String upperCaseDestination = itinerary.get(itinerary.size()-1 ).toUpperCase();
        travelRoute.append(upperCaseDestination );
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check if its the last one. If its not, add "to".

```
StringBuilder travelRoute = new StringBuilder(); 
for(int count = 0; count < itinerary.size() ; count++)
{
    String upperCaseDestination = itinerary.get(count).toUpperCase();
    travelRoute.append(upperCaseDestination);
    if(i<itenerary.size()-1){
        travelRoute.append("to");
    }
}
```